# Each Loop in Rails 4 Controller to create new instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent form (lead) and child form (QuoteMetal) (which is rendered multiple times on the same submit). All the information from the forms gets written to their respective data tables, but I need the information from the child forms to perform a query and return those values. I have the forms created and a controller which writes the information to the data tables.

I need help with making the query results for each of the child forms then accessing them in the views. Here is what I currently have.

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lead = Lead.new
    @quote_metal = @lead.quote_metals.build
  end

  def create
    #raise params.inspect
    @lead = Lead.create!(lead_params) #write to data tables (which works)
    @lead.quote_metals.each do |f|
      @metal = Metal.calculate_metal(f).first #here is where my problem is! the     #calculate_metal is the query located in my model
    end
  end

  def show
  end

private

    def lead_params
        params.require(:lead).permit([:name, ..... 
            quote_metals_attributes: [:id...],
      quote_melees_attributes: [:shape...],
      quote_diamonds_attributes: [:shape...]
      ])
    end

end
```

and the view:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2'>
      <h3 class="text-center">Your Search: </h3>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-5'>
        <h4 class="text-center">Returning estimates for a <%= @metal.metal %> setting
       weighing <%= @metal.weight %> <%= @metal.unit %>. I am paying
       <%= number_to_currency(@metal.price, precision: 2) %> per <%= @metal.unit %>.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actions on `QuoteMetal` instances should be handled in the `QuoteMetal` class.  So, I would replace:

```
@lead.quote_metals.each do |f|
  @metal = Metal.calculate_metal(f).first #here is where my problem is! the     #calculate_metal is the query located in my model
end
```

with:

```
@lead.quote_metals.each do |f|
  f.create
end
```

And then in your `QuoteMetal` class, you can use a [before_save](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) callback and perform the calculation there.  Keep in mind this will invoke `calculate_metal` every time a `QuoteMetal` is saved or updated.

Even better would be to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the `Lead` model so that quote_metals can be automatically created when leads are created.  See Rails documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). With this approach, you could eliminate the above three lines in the controller, but would still need the callback in the `QuoteMetal` class to perform the custom calculation.

Separately, be aware that your call to `create!` will raise an exception if validation fails.  Not sure you intend that.

Comment: I do the accepts_nested_attributes_for in the leads model. I am wondering how I could preform the query on each instance of the @lead.quote_metals and how I refer to each of those queries and results in a view. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: You need to redirect to some other action or render some other view.  For instance, if @lead has the created lead instance (with associated quote_metal instances), you could `render 'show'` after successfully creating a lead to show the lead and the associated quote_metals.